# How to run a r code in linux after locking the screen?

Tags: r, screen-lock

I am running a code in R that takes a long time to give me the results. I lock the PC (Linux OS) and it continues to run but after one hour or so the Rstudio closes automatically and when I unlock the screen I see that Rstudio is closed and the running of code has stopped. How can I prevent R from stopping. I have disabled the PC from going to sleep or being suspended.

Comment: run from terminal? `Rscript yourscript.R`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Running from terminal takes more time than running from Rstudio. At this point, time really matters to me.

Comment: That's great. I had not heard of Rstudio performance improvements to running R scripts.

Comment: I checked my code again, you are right there is no difference in terms of running time for running as Rscript or running in Rstudio. I really appreciate your quick response, thank you so much, it helped me a lot.